# Do Solamnic Knights get paid?

Tags: dragonlance

I had a question already asked here:
[How do men of the Night's Watch pay for visits to Mole's Town?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66057/how-do-men-of-the-nights-watch-pay-for-visits-to-moles-town)

But the question is not really answered. I know the Night's Watch is not the Knights of Solamnia Order, but I want to ask the same question about them. It's been a really long time since I read the novels, so I don't know if there's any clue about Solamnic Knights being paid as a regular army.

BTW, I think that they also swear an oath (Est sularis oth mithas, My Honor is my Life, or something like that). Do they swear for life?

Comment: IIRC, when Sturm was made a knight, it was mentioned that he'd get paid according to his rank. I can look this up. Also, I think your second question deserves it's own question, so that this one doesn't get muddled. But that's just me.

Comment: I think that you might be right, but if they swear and are bonded to the Order for life, then that is something that may affect if they are paid and if more or less than a regular soldier. That's why I added that paragraph. Sorry if it creates more noise on the site.

Comment: Many of them were also from noble families and had estates for income (during the time of their power, anyway)

Comment: @BBlake, OK, but that can't be the norm. I guess that that helps to clarify that they are not a mercenary company (or noblemen would not join), but stating that some might be already wealthy when joining the Order doesn't clarify if they were paid (either nothing,  little for basic maintenance or as a regular army, because they might finish their relationship with the Order and manage their own businesses).

Comment: It's been a long time, but if I recall correctly, the two highest orders of Knights were almost exclusively nobility.  The lowest order of Knights were where the lesser applicants would stay.  I believe MyCodeSucks is correct in that there was a stipend paid to Knights, and I also believe it was a commitment for life.  They were, for all intents and purposes, a divine order, devoted to Paladine and his two sons (Kiri-Jolith and Habbakuk).  It was one of the reasons they were so hated after the destruction of Istar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do not receive payment, quite the opposite. Part of being a Solmanic Knight means you give some of your income to the Solamnic Knight institution to support the training, feeding, lodging, and upkeep of the Solmanic Knight empire.

Knights of the Crown are expected to give 10% of their wealth (or income) to the official coffers.

Knights of the Sword and Rose are expected to give 100% of wealth except those required for upkeep for lands or property (castles, fortresses).

Before Gunthar's modification of the Measure, most knights (or all) were historically royalty from Solamnia, and therefore had lands and other resources at their disposal. Presumably they may impose a tax on the people living and working their lands in return for their protection. It is stated that before the Catacylsm, there were only 69 total Solamnic Knights, all others were

> conscripted army, footmen, usually local guards, militia and mercenaries, acting under the commands of a Knight - [dragonlance.wiki](http://dragonlance.wikia.com/wiki/Solamnic_Knights#)

There were even fewer after the Catacylsm.

When Laurana became the popular Golden General, there was a huge surge in enlistment in the knighthood. Gunthar Uth Wistan remarked that their coffers were 'full' for the first time in years. This is probably on account of receiving the income of new squires and knights of the crown who had enlisted, in addition to donations from cities (such as Palanthas). The knights were now seen as favorable for the first time in 300 years.

> During several centuries, the Knighthood only accepted squires coming from noble families located in Solamnia...In more recent times, squires can enter the order so long as they are honorable. - [dragonlance.wiki](http://dragonlance.wikia.com/wiki/Solamnic_Knights#)

An example of this would be Tanin and Sturm Majere, who were not from Solamnia (or royalty), but were both accepted into the Knights of Solamnia.

Those knights who didn't come from royalty probably had very little, but as knights they had no reason to seek riches. They were provided with clothing, weapons, food, lodging, and mounts (circumstances providing). As knights they lived frugal lives.

The oath is `Est Sularis Oth Mithas`, `My Honor is my Life`. The Measure is a set of rules by which a knight is expected to behave in any number of situations. Unless a knight acts in a dishonorable way, he is a member for life. If he is found to be dishonorable before a council, he may be disbanded from the knighthood (such as Lord Soth), or lowered in rank.

Comment: Thanks. Link to the wiki was really helpful. I understand form your answer that the military force know as Solamnic Knights are both knight and "conscripted army, footmen[...] militia and mercenaries" which are definitely going to be paid. Knights are not paid, and those wealthy use part of their wealth to uphold the order (I seem to remember that Lord Soth had his own fortes, and resisted siege there after being outcasted from the Order).

Comment: Lord Soth's retainers were extremely loyal to him.